# SwiftUI Strange results with nested Foreach loops with LazyVGrid

Tags: multidimensional-array, swiftui, swiftui-foreach

From a lot of comments it is well known, that nested Foreach loops sometimes don't work as expected. However, up to now I didn't find a solution for the problem.
The code example should produce a vie with the content

```
ad   ae   af
bd   be   bf
```

However, only the first line is displayed.
The reason is quite clear formulated by the error messages:

> LazyVGridLayout: the ID d is used by multiple child views, this will give undefined results!
> LazyVGridLayout: the ID e is used by multiple child views, this will give undefined results!
> LazyVGridLayout: the ID f is used by multiple child views, this will give undefined results!

Does somebody know how to solve the problem?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let rowData = ["a", "b"]
    let colData = ["d", "e", "f"]
    let colums = [GridItem(), GridItem(), GridItem()]
    
    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: colums) {
            ForEach(rowData, id: \.self) { rowItem in

                ForEach(colData, id: \.self) {colItem in
                    Text(rowItem + colItem)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LazyVGrid` layout is getting confused with the `ID` of the Views it is presenting.

So give it a unique `id` for each `Text` view. Like this:

```
 Text(rowItem + colItem).id(rowItem + colItem)
```

Works for me.

Comment: This solution works fine. However, it is not clear to me, that id(rowItem + colItem) results in a unique id. Your hint with an id for the view lead me to another possibility: id(UUID()) which should be unique.

Comment: Typically in real prolects, the `rowData` and `colData` are data models (struct) with a unique id, and
 that is what is often used. Ceryainly `id(UUID())` is unique and works.